# using for loop inside promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am having a scenario where
Step 1: i have run a loop and push the data into an array
step 2: once my first loop is complete I will start second loop to push data into the same array

I have tried async function, this is my example use case

```
  var arr =[]; //declared globally
    async function myloop(){

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    arr.push(i);
    }

    }

   // Here is what I wanna do now
    myloop().then(function(){
    for(i=10;i<20;i++){
    arr.push(i)
    }
    })
```

I have to wait until my function pushes all the data in the loop, after loop completion I need to come back here for second run

Comment: Is any of the data you're pushing from an async source? Else you won't need promises. So can you please give more context about what data is and what the relation between the different data points is.

Comment: What is your question? What isn’t working?

Comment: needs more information what do want to do

Comment: I am pulling over data from a cloud Database from two collections, I am trying to pull the duplicates during the first loop and then during the second loop I'm going to add it to display. while I am running two for loops they are running asycnchronously so I went with async and promises. but Stilll array is returned before loop completes

Comment: Use a `for..of` loop which supports `await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is a bit unclear, but I assume that you are receiving two arrays from two collections, which returns the array in a `Promise`.

Let's suppose you have these two functions.

```
function dataBaseCallX() {
    // returns a Promise<Array>
}

function dataBaseCallY() {
    // returns a Promise<Array>
}
```

And you want to combine both the results right? Then here you can use the async-await feature. I think this is what you want.

```
const resultA = await dataBaseCallX();  // An Array
const resultB = await dataBaseCallY();  // An Array

let combinedResults = resultA.concat(resultB);
```

If in case of errors, you can simply wrap this into a try catch block.